# Prove ($Y_1$,$Y_2$) is normal bivariate if $Y_1$ = $X_1$ and $Y_2$=$X_1 + X_2$ with $X_i \backsim N(\mu_i,\sigma_i^2)$ independent

Tags: probability, random-variables, gaussian

I'm struggling a little with this question. It's clear to me that $Y_2$ is normal because it is a linear combination of two normals. However, as I understand it, not EVERY vector of univariate normals is normal, and so proving ($Y_1$,$Y_2$) is bivariate is not as trivial as stating that its components are normals.

I have tried to do so by finding $f(y_1,y_2)$ from $f(y_1)$ (which is a normal) and $f(y_2|y_1)$ (which can be found using the conditional cdf of $y_2$ given $y1$). However, the algebra doesn't quite work out and I'm missing a few terms. I also tried it using the integral transformation theorem from ($X_1,X_2$) to ($X_1,X_1+X_2$) but I get the same result.

I currently have this:
with $\mu_1 = E[X_1]$, $\sigma_1^2 = Var(X_1)$, $\mu_2 = E[X_2]$, $\sigma_2^2 = Var(X_2)$

$f(y_1,y_2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_1}e^{\frac{-1}{2}(\frac{y_1-\mu_1}{\sigma_1})^2} * \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}\sigma_2}e^{\frac{-1}{2}(\frac{y_2-y_1-\mu_2}{\sigma_2})^2}$

I got this through both methods, but I have no idea how to get the normal bivariate density function from there.

**¿Is there another way to prove that the vector is bivariate normal? ¿Or any hints with the algebra required.**

Comment: I think you should mention somewhere that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent for your conclusion to hold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are correlated, so you need to write your pdf in the general [Bivariate Normal](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BivariateNormalDistribution.html) probability density function (re-written below for the record):

$$f(y_1,y_2)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_{y_1}\sigma_{y_2}\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\exp\left[-\frac{z}{2(1-\rho^2)}\right]$$
with:
$$z=\frac{(y_1-\mu_{y_1})^2}{\sigma_{y_1}^2}-\frac{2(y_1-\mu_{y_1})(y_2-\mu_{y_2})}{\sigma_{y_1}\sigma_{y_2}}+\frac{(y_2-\mu_{y_2})^2}{\sigma_{y_2}^2}$$
and:
$$\rho=\frac{\operatorname{Cov}(Y_1,Y_2)}{\sigma_{y_1}\sigma_{y_2}}$$

In your case you have $\mu_{y_1}=\mu_1,\ \mu_{y_2}=\mu_1+\mu_2,\ \sigma_{y_1}^2=\sigma_1^2,\ \sigma_{y_2}^2=\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2,\text{ and }\rho=\frac{\sigma_1}{\sqrt{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2}}$

If you know matrix algebra and you know that non-singular linear transformations of multivariate normal random variables is also multivariate normal, you can write:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
Y_1 \\ Y_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
X_1 \\ X_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$
is nonsingular,
$\begin{bmatrix}
X_1 \\ X_2
\end{bmatrix}$
is multivariate normal, and voila!

Comment: Yes! I got that far (calculating the correlation correctly). But it's exactly that what's bothering me. How would I get $\sqrt{1-\rho^2}$ into the denominator if it doesn't show up in either (and multiplying both numerator and denominator si weird since then I would have it in the numerator where it doesn't go

Comment: Do you mean $\sigma_{y1}\sigma_{y2}\sqrt{1-\rho^2}=\sigma_1\sqrt{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2}\sqrt{1-\frac{\sigma_1^2}{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2}}=\sigma_1\sigma_2$? BTW, in your formula for $f(y_1,y_2)$ I think that $2$ should be inside the square root.

Comment: The linear algebra solution was exactly what I needed. Thanks!